# Is UIViewController's default background black?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I created this simple demo. The main storyboard is like this:

[image]

Code in that view controller is as below:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController* secondVC = [SecondViewController new];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}

@end
```

In appdelegate.m there's:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return YES;
}
```

In SecondViewController.m there's nothing but the default code.

The problem is, the SecondViewController appears to be black, and there's a obvious lag during the push animation. However, when I set SecondViewController's backgroundColor to any color(for example red), there's no lag and everything appears to be normal. I'm testing this on iOS 8, and it is this way on both the simulator and iPhone device.

I have never seen this before. Is UIViewController's default background transparent or black? Or what am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no nib for `SecondViewController`. First add view controller to story board and go to utilities in xcode(right panel) -> identity inspector(third icon), here set its class name to `SecondViewController`and storyboard Id "SecondViewController", then change button click event as :

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController * secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is that I don't want to use storyboard or nib for SecondViewController. What should I write then?

Comment: If view for `SecondViewController` is not present there, then it always shows black screen. You need to set color of view. `SecondViewController *secondVC = [SecondViewController new];
    secondVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];`

Comment: The reason why it shows a black color not because the view is not present there!  It is because the view has a transparent color and because the default main window has a black color.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what went wrong might be this line if your controller is in storyboard

```
SecondViewController* secondVC = [SecondViewController new];
```

Here you are doing `alloc init`, which will not initialise the `SecondViewController` completely unless you are overriding the `init` method. If your `SecondViewController` is in storyboard use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

```
SecondViewController* secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you Anil, I don't want to use storyboard or nib for SecondViewController. What should I write instead of that?

Comment: Why no storyboard no xib? In that case you have create everything programmatically. By default viewController view doesnt have any color. you have to set in `init`. If your ar doing this for learning go ahead, going to be a big pain for you. otherwise use storyboard to design your view.

Comment: What is wrong with this line: SecondViewController* secondVC = [SecondViewController new]; ?

Comment: @user523234 nothing wrong. I suggested for easy implementation

Comment: if the controller is in storyboard, and doing`[SecondViewController new]` will not give the expected output. I'am not saying `[SecondViewController new]` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you both :) I don't have a problem with storyboard. I'm just curious if it's transparent by default or am I missing something. Now that I know it's actually transparent, I'll set background color explicitly without further concern.